# Flutter input decoration suffixIcon not appearing but always showing cross symbol

Tags: input, flutter

I have the following example codes. I have now managed to put the prefixicon and it works fine. I want to move the same icon the suffix meaning on the right hand side but it just does not work but the X symbol it what appears.
Here is a screen shot.
[image]

I have added the following lines suffixIcon: IconButton( but it seems not be appearing but the one on the left hand side which is the prefix appears perfectly fine. I cant get the one on the right hand side. What is blocking it from appearing?

Below is my codes.

```
class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // Show some different formats.
  final formats = {
    //InputType.both: DateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mma"),
    //InputType.date: DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy'),
    //InputType.time: DateFormat("HH:mm"),
    InputType.date: DateFormat("d MMMM  yyyy"),
  };
  //InputType.date: DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'),
  // Changeable in demo
  InputType inputType = InputType.date;
  bool editable = true;
  DateTime date;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(appName)),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[

            Form(
          //key: _myKey,
          child: Column(
             children : [

              new Container(              
                width: 200.0,
                child:new DateTimePickerFormField(

                            dateOnly: true,
                            format: formats[inputType],
                            editable: false,
                            validator: (val) {
                              if (val != null) {
                                return null;
                              } else {
                                return 'Date Field is Empty';
                              }
                            },
                            /*decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              labelText: 'From',contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0)),*/
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'To',
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  filled: false,
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    size: 28.0,
                  ),
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down,size: 28),
                      onPressed: () {
                        debugPrint('222');
                      })),
                   initialValue: DateTime.now().subtract(new Duration(days: 7)), //Add this in your Code.

                  ),

              )
             ]


          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            /*if (_myKey.currentState.validate()) {
              _myKey.currentState.save();
            } else {
            }*/ print("check;");
            if(emailController.text.isEmpty){
              print("TEST;");
                //valid = false;
                //emailError = "Email can't be blank!";
                //openAlertBox();
                Toast.show("Empty Date From", context, backgroundColor: Colors.red );

            } 
            else{
              print("not empty;");
              final f = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
              final original = new DateFormat('d MMMM  yyyy');

              print("Format datre is"+emailController.text);
              print("Formate date :"+original.parse(emailController.text).toString());



            }
          },
          child: Text('Submit'),
        )

          ],
        ),
      ));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I re-created your case by singling out only the `TextFormField` code you provided and was able to see the `dropdown arrow` as `suffixIcon`.

[image]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .height,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children : [
              new Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                width: 200.0,
                  child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'To',
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      filled: false,
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        size: 28.0,
                      ),
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down,size: 28),
                          onPressed: () {
                            debugPrint('222');
                          })),
                ),
              )
        ]
              )
        ),
      )
      );
  }
}
```

I see that you used `Padding` as your `body` to return `Scaffold`. Try to replace it with `Center` or `Container`

Comment: I dont get you what do you mean by padding ?

Comment: You've `body: Padding` in build function. Try to replace it with `Container`. because it seems there is an issue with the padding due to which you are not able to see icon at suffix position.

Comment: I saw you replace the padding with center right. what other option do I have besides this

Answer (score 2):

You may have discovered the following but posting just in case...

The 'X' displayed is the reset icon for the date field ie. you use that to clear the field. You can turn it off with DateTimePickerFormField property 'resetIcon: null;' but then the only way to remove a date from the field is to ensure 'editable: true', which is the default but you have overridden it in your code.
Hope that helps.